# how to get value of stdClass Object foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta_id] => 11
    [post_id] => 8
    [meta_key] => wpp_gpid
    [meta_value] => gpid_1124779119
)
stdClass Object
(
    [meta_id] => 12
    [post_id] => 8
    [meta_key] => _edit_last
    [meta_value] => 1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [meta_id] => 13
    [post_id] => 8
    [meta_key] => _edit_lock
    [meta_value] => 1346228510:1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [meta_id] => 16
    [post_id] => 8
    [meta_key] => _thumbnail_id
    [meta_value] => 9
)
```

This is print_r value of
`$poster_meta = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = '{$poster}'");`

How do i get the `meta_value` of `meta_key = thumbnail` and `meta_key = _edit_last`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to get meta key value in wordpress then

try this code:-

```
$team_counter = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'team_counter', true);
```

get_post_meta is wordpress library default function

Comment: yes i know what is your question but this is right approach. I think we should follow correct rule of word press.you can user $arg_post = array(
     'post_type'=>'portfolio',
     'meta_key' => 'is_high_profile',
     'meta_value' => 'yes',
     'orderby' => 'title',
     'order' => 'ASC'
     
    ); 
         
   $query = new WP_Query($arg_post); inseted or you query.

Answer (score 5):

Treat it as an object. Check [how objects](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) work.

```
foreach($poster_meta as $object){
    echo $object->meta_id."\n";
    echo $object->post_id."\n";
    echo $object->meta_key."\n";
    echo $object->meta_value."\n";
}
```